# include external sqlite3 database to iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, ios, database

I have a sqlite3 database, created by another application. And now I need to use this database in my new iPhone application. I tried many variations, but nothing works...
How can I get path to main folder with appdelegate.h and viewcontroller.h (for example) files? How can I include to project my "base.sqlite" file, situated in this main folder?
Or maybe another solutions? Upper/lower case I checked, there is another error in my situation. File exist on device, I checked it with     BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path];

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You somehow need to copy the pre-constructed SQLite file from the bundle into writable storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the sqlite3 file in your resources and then use:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"base" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

if you create a subdirectory, you can use:

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] @"base" @"sqlite" inDirectory:yourDirectory];
```

Comment: My file situated in folder with all *.h and *.m files. When I use     NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"base" ofType:@"sqlite"] - its works on simulator, but not works when I try testing on iPhone

Comment: make sure that your file is listed in the "copy bundle resources" phase for your target... it is the only thing I can come up with...

Comment: How can I get path to myDirectory? Its not a problem when I used simulator, but problem with iPhone

Comment: sergio: checked, my file is listed in the "copy bundle resources"

Comment: the directory depends on where you put the file in the project. You can inspect your app bundle structure if you go to the build directory, select the bundle and then right-click on "Show package content". By the way, are you sure that on the device `path` is nil? or which error are you getting?

Comment: mainBundle on simulator get /Users/sasha/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/E4619F8A-9865-4867-8873-8E8728DD48B3/Scanword.app/base.sqlite and working! in iPhone main Bundle get /var/mobile/Applications/C42E677E-7947-40A7-B46B-94B57C941DF6/Scanword.app/base.sqlite and not working... Error: SIGABRT: Scanword[512:707] *** Assertion failure in -[ScanWord setZadaniyaToList::], /Users/sasha/Documents/Scanword/Scanword/Scanword/ScanWord.m:454
 Scanword[512:707] ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to open database'

Comment: have you inspected the bundle content to check that the file is there?

Comment: I went to DerivedData Path, found the Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Scanword.app, inspected package and found my database file. Do you mean this?

Comment: Solved. Problem was in too good memory xcode, it use old part of code instead of the current